# opening local html file with Android Browser

Tags: android, browser, uri

i'm trying to open a local html file using the default browser using the following code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(uri);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

but i'm getting the following exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/SolveDroid/solution.html }
```

i'm confused - should i create an activity to hande the web beowser? isn't it supposed to just call its activity?

please advise :)

**UPDATE:**
the same code works if i pass a URL like so:
 `Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.metalist.co.il");`

Comment: Which activity you are starting? your code says startActivity() but which one?

Comment: what do you mean?
am i supposed to call a specific Activity? isn't the default Browser an activity already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer for this problem... just needed to add

```
browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
```

i used it with the "file://" uri by using `Uri.fromfile(file)` and it works (Android v.2.2.1)

Answer (score 9):

```
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
    browserIntent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: `file` has to be in this format: `file://sdcard/somedir/somefile`

Comment: Does not work on Android 3.2 nor 4.0.4 see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10104244 any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            File f=new File("/sdcard/html.html");
            in.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "text/html");
            startActivity(in);
```

Comment: A few short years later, the /sdcard folder has disappeared (in exchange for an incomprehensible nest of "external private folders"). Where do I write the temporary file so the web browser can read it?