# Opening a content:// url in android browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm building an app that uses a custom content provider to serve HTML pages (as if it were a web server, but serving from a data source).  From an Activity, I would like to send the user to a page using the content:// scheme, but I would like to use the default app that handles browseable URIs (instead of just the android browser, to accommodate a different default browser by the user).

Working from the answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532319/1524800 (my implementation is basically identical), I'm able to open the the default android browser explicitly, but I would prefer to use the user's default browser using an implicit intent.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

To do that instead of this

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
browserIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

try this

```
final Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/html");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Open with..."));
```

Comment: Doesn't work... This still shows no options for an item to choose, most likely because there was no filter matching the intent to begin with.