# Open an activity window in Android WebView passing a String in JavaScript?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-webview

I want to open an activity window in Android WebView passing a String in JavaScript, but I always get this undefined error:

> 05-18 06:32:02.586  13351-13351/com.vaydesign.tw3 I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'openActivity' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/index.html
>   (11)

Part of my `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    // Caching
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    public Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void openActivity(String activity){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(activity));
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="entry" onclick="window.JSInterface.openActivity('About');">About</div>
```

Comment: Did you add your JavascriptInterface to your WebView? Like `webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), 
    INTERFACE_NAME);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add annotation @javascriptInterface over openActivity method.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void openActivity(String activity){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(activity));
    mContext.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the annotation and this is the new error: `05-18 08:02:03.146  12469-12469/com.vaydesign.tw3 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation", source: file:///android_asset/about.html (10)
05-18 08:02:03.296  12469-12664/com.vaydesign.tw3 W/System.err﹕ android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=About }`

Comment: have a look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293786/opening-local-html-file-with-android-browser

Comment: Sadly, this didn't helped me. He is passing a File object and I'm just passing a String object via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The interfaceName you set in

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

is "Android", you should use it in

```
<div class="entry" onclick="window.Android.openActivity('About');">About</div>
```

Comment: Now it says: `"Uncaught TypeError: window.Android.openActivity is not a function"`

Comment: Annotate all your public interface methods you want to access in javascript with @JavascriptInterface, also `Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` this type of UI method should use `runOnUiThread` or a Handler to execute on UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added the annotation and this is the new error: `05-18 08:02:03.146  12469-12469/com.vaydesign.tw3 I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation", source: file:///android_asset/about.html (10)
05-18 08:02:03.296  12469-12664/com.vaydesign.tw3 W/System.err﹕ android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=About }`

Comment: That's another problem with Intent, I think the Uri you passed in the intent is illegal, you should check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day debugging a similar issue, I was getting the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: window.Android.openActivity is not a function"

I had set my annotated method to private by mistake.

Check your method signature to make sure it is public if you are  going to be calling it from Javascript.